# How can I configure postgreSQL in the Nestjs way?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nestjs

So I'm in the process of learning NestJs ways. I have a small NestJs backend with only a few routes. Some of them call postgreSQL. I don't want to use any ORM and directly use pg package.
So my next step is learning how to use ConfigService. I have successfully used it to configure all env vars in the backend, but I'm struggling to use it in a small file I use to configure postgreSQL. This is the configuration file (pgconnect.ts):

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';
import configJson from './config/database.json';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const config = configJson[process.env.NODE_ENV];

const poolConfig = {
  user: config.username,
  host: config.host,
  database: config.database,
  password: config.password,
  port: config.port,
  max: config.maxClients
};

export const pool = new Pool(poolConfig)
```

database.json is a json file where I have all connect values divided by environment. Then in service classes I just:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';
import { pool } from 'src/database/pgconnect';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    getDocumentByName(res: Response, name: string) {
        pool.query(
               <query, error treatment, etc>
            });
    }

    <...> more queries for insert, update, other selects, etc
}
```

So how could I use ConfigService inside my configuration file ? I already tried to instance class like this:

```
let configService = new ConfigService();
```

and what I would like to do is:

```
const config = configJson[configService.get<string>('NODE_ENV')];
```

but it didn't work. You have to pass .env file path to `new ConfigService()`. And I need to use NODE_ENV var to get it, because it depends on environment. To get NODE_ENV without using ConfigService I would have to use dotenv, but if I'm going to use dotenv I don't need ConfigService in the first place.

So then I tried to create a class:

```
import { Injectable, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'
const { Pool } = require('pg');

import configJson from './config/database.json';

@Injectable()
export class PgPool {
    constructor(private configService: ConfigService) { };

    config = configJson[this.configService.get<string>('NODE_ENV')];

    poolConfig = {
        user: this.config.username,
        host: this.config.host,
        database: this.config.database,
        password: this.config.password,
        port: this.config.port,
        max: this.config.maxClients
    };
    
    static pool = new Pool(this.poolConfig);
}

export const PgPool.pool;
```

But this doesn't work in several ways. If I use non-static members, I can´t export pool member which is the only thing I need. If I use static members one can't access the other or at least I'm not understanding how one access the other.

So, the questions are: How do I use ConfigService outside of a class or how can I change pgconnect.ts file to do it's job ? If it's through a class the best would be to export only pool method.

Also if you think there's a better way to configure postgreSQL I would be glad to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do, if you're going to be using the `pg` package directly, is create a `PgModule` that exposes the `Pool` you create as a provider that can be injected. Then you can also create a provider for the options specifically for ease of swapping in test. Something like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'PG_OPTIONS',
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config) => ({
        host: config.get('DB_HOST'),
        port:  config.get('DB_PORT'),
        ...etc
      }),
    },
    {
      provide: 'PG_POOL',
      inject: ['PG_OPTIONS'],
      useFactory: (options) => new Pool(options),
    }
  ],
  exports: ['PG_POOL'],
})
export class PgModule {}
```

Now, when you need to use the `Pool` in another service you add `PgModule` to that service's module's `imports` and you add `@Inject('PG_POOL') private readonly pg: Pool` to the service's `constructor`.

[If you want to see an overly engineered solution, you can take a look at my old implementation here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaPlay/tree/main/apps/api/src/app/database)

Comment: I had to read a bit to understand what you have made, but it was very useful and what I needed to understand NestJs better. Worked like a charm. Thanks. 
I saw that you are one of NestJs contributors. I'm really liking NestJs and intend to use it as my backend of choice from now on. Please transmit my congratulations for this awesome fw to you coleagues on NestJs team. Next step: configuring Passport-jwt with a decent asymetric algorithm :)

Answer (score 1):

I normally have my own pg module handling the pool with either an additional config file (json) or via processing a .env file:

node-pg-sql.js:

```
/* INFO: Require json config file */
const fileNameConfigPGSQL = require('./config/pgconfig.json');

/* INFO: Require file operations package */
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool(fileNameConfigPGSQL);

module.exports = {
  query: (text, params, callback) => {
    const start = Date.now()
    return pool.query(text, params, (err, res) => {
      const duration = Date.now() - start
  //    console.log('executed query', { text, duration, rows: res.rowCount })
      callback(err, res)
    })
  },
  getClient: (callback) => {
    pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
      const query = client.query.bind(client)

      // monkey patch for the query method to track last queries
      client.query = () => {
        client.lastQuery = arguments
        client.query.apply(client, arguments)
      }

      // Timeout of 5 secs,then last query is logged
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
     //   console.error('A client has been checked out for more than 5 seconds!')
     //   console.error(`The last executed query on this client was: ${client.lastQuery}`)
      }, 5000)

      const release = (err) => {
        // calling 'done'-method to return client to pool
        done(err)

        // cleat timeout
        clearTimeout(timeout)

        // reset query-methode before the Monkey Patch
        client.query = query
      }

      callback(err, client, done)
    })
  }
}
```

pgconfig.json:

```
{
    "user":"postgres",
    "host":"localhost",
    "database":"mydb",
    "password":"mypwd",
    "port":"5432",
    "ssl":true
}
```

If you prefer processing a .env file:

```
NODE_ENV=develepment
NODE_PORT=45500
HOST_POSTGRESQL='localhost'
PORT_POSTGRESQL='5432'
DB_POSTGRESQL='mydb'
USER_POSTGRESQL='postgres'
PWD_POSTGRESQL='mypwd'
```

and process the file and export vars:

```
var path = require('path');


const dotenvAbsolutePath = path.join(__dirname, '.env');

/* INFO: Require dotenv package for retieving and setting env-vars at runtime via absolute path due to pkg */

  const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({
    path: dotenvAbsolutePath
  });
  if (dotenv.error) {
    console.log(`ERROR WHILE READING ENV-VARS:${dotenv.error}`);
    throw dotenv.error;
  }

module.exports = {
  nodeEnv: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  nodePort: process.env.NODE_PORT,
  hostPostgresql: process.env.HOST_POSTGRESQL,
  portPostgresql: process.env.PORT_POSTGRESQL,
  dbPostgresql: process.env.DB_POSTGRESQL,
  userPostgresql: process.env.USER_POSTGRESQL,
  pwdPostgresql: process.env.PWD_POSTGRESQL,
};
```

Comment: Yes, I had been using something similar in other projects. But notice that I wanted to know the "NestJs way" of doing things :) But thanks anyway.